# Some favorite jobs are not shown in favorites page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Some of my favorite jobs are not shown in favorites page, although they are available on "your favorites" side panel.  For example [this](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/47997) and [this](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/62006) jobs.

> [image]

Comment: Reproduced, added a screenshot.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks!

Comment: No repro for me here - are you still seeing this behaviour?

Comment: @AlexWarren Yes.

Comment: I'm not seeing a site visit from your user since yesterday, JohnS. Can you try logging in again?

Comment: @AlexWarren My main career account is not connected to this account, I have just used this account to reproduce the issue. Anyway I have just logged in again (with this account) and the issue still exists.

Comment: Can you send me a link to your careers user profile page (click your name at the top of the screen), so I can reproduce the issue? If you don't want this to be public you can email it: awarren (and the rest of the email address should hopefully be obvious).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed.

The problem was occurring because many jobs are only listed in particular geographic regions. If you visit the website from a region where a particular job is not listed, it won't appear in search results.

We were filtering out jobs from the favorites page, but not the favorites list in the sidebar. So if you visited us from one region, added a job to your favorites list, then visted us from a different region, that job would still be in your sidebar list, but might be filtered out of your favorites page itself. Which was silly.

I've now changed this so that your favorites page is not filtered based on your region, so you will always be able to see all of your favorites.

Comment: What you mean by "visit from a region"? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: As in, a geographic region. If you're visiting from Europe, you'll see different search results than if you're visiting from Japan etc.

Comment: Thanks, and you decide my region based on my IP? Or using a different method?

Comment: Yes, it entirely depends on your IP address.